# Расположить коммиты последовательно

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Нашел, что для этого нужна команда:

```
git rebase
```

Не пойму, как ей пользоваться, *about* читал. Я делаю такую последовательность операций:

```
 commit -a 
 pull -v mybranch ourbranch
 rebase ???
 push -v mybranch ourbranch
```

Пытаюсь передать разные параметры, использовать ключи либо выбираю действие из списка, но ничего не получается. Иногда не ругается, вроде что-то выполняет, но результат нулевой. А иногда пишет ошибку:

> "Interactive rebase already started"

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос непонятен. Автор не пояснил, что он имеет в виду под "расположить последовательно". Ответы в итоге тоже малоинформативны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я, к сожалению, не понял, что Вам надо… Если почётче сформулируете вопрос, попытаюсь подсказать.

Пока же могу посоветовать Вам отличную книжку [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/) — доступна онлайн. Читается очень легко и быстро, буквально за один вечер. В частности там есть [довольно подробное описание rebase](http://progit.org/book/ch3-6.html).

Comment: Всё равно не понятно… Как сейчас коммиты расположены? Посмотреть бы своими глазами. Я вот ссылку Вам дал на конкретные примеры использование rebase. Неужели ни один из них не помог?

Comment: К сожалению, да. Чаще всего ошибка из заглавного сообщения ("Interactive rebase already started"). А случай я пытаюсь рассмотреть самый простой: 1 мой коммит, 1 чужой коммит, конфликтов нет.

Comment: Так а что Вас собрались последовательно располагать, если у Вас и так только два коммита, идущие друг за другом?? Они же и так последовательно идут!

Comment: Нет, ну там понятно, две ветки - в каждой по коммиту, и в итоге получается, что они соединяются в одну при коммите "Merge mybranch/ourbrach", который не содержит ни одного изменения (пустой). Вот я и пытаюсь эти ветки слить в одну. Они в gitk идут не в линию, а именно с этим мержом, которого по сути нет

Comment: Чёрт, я всё равно не понимаю :(. Ну вот у Вас было две ветки. Вы их решили слить в одну merg'ем — соответственно, создался коммит, в который они сошлись. Дальше они уже будут как одна «расти» из этого третьего коммита. В чём с этим проблема? Или Вы просто принципиально хотите эти два коммита в линию сделать?

Comment: @kirelagin Тестовый комментарий, не обращайте внимания

Answer (score 0):

```
git commit
git pull --rebase
git rebase --continue # если вдруг понадобился мерж
git push
```